# Integral of a product of the normal pdf with one over sum of exponents

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximation

I am trying to compute an integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ce^{kx} + \frac{1}{c}e^{-kx}}N(x; \mu, \sigma^2) \, dx,$$ where $N(x; \mu, \sigma^2)$ is a normal pdf w.r.t. $x$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Just by the looks of the function $\frac{1}{ce^{kx} + \frac{1}{c}e^{-kx}}$ it seems that this integral should converge -- for $x$ going to plus and minus infinity this fraction is 0, so "the area under the curve" is finite. Wolfram Alpha ran out of time and did not give an answer.

Dropping some of the prefactors, I get that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ce^{kx} + \frac{1}{c}e^{-kx}}N(x; \mu, \sigma^2) \, dx \sim \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2+x(2\mu - 2k\sigma^2)}{2\sigma^2}}}{1 + \frac{1}{c^2}e^{-2kx}} \, dx,$$
but I do not see where to go from here.
I know that for specific values of $x$, $k$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$ it is possible to find the answer numerically, but I would like to have an expression for it.

I have also tried to look for approximations (e.g. I know that for logistic-normal integrals there exist approximations), but I am not sure whether there is a special name for functions of the form $\frac{1}{ce^{kx} + \frac{1}{c}e^{-kx}}$.

Is there a way to solve this integral or write an approximation in terms of $x$, $k$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approximation for your integral can be obtained by applying the saddle point method to $$\begin{align} \left\langle f(x) \right\rangle& := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,  \sigma} \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\!  dx \, e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}f(x)\\ &= \left\langle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(\mu)}{n!}(x-\mu)^n \right\rangle\\ &=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(2k)}(\mu)}{(2k)!} \left\langle (x-\mu)^{2k} \right\rangle \\ &= f(\mu) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(2k)}(\mu)}{(2k)!} (2k-1)!! \, \sigma^{2k} \\ &= f(\mu) +f^{\prime \prime}(\mu) \sigma^2 /2 \, +f^{IV}(\mu) \sigma^4/8 + \ldots,\end{align}$$ giving $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \, \sigma} \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \! dx \, e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \frac{1}{c e^{kx}+e^{-kx}/c} \simeq \frac{1}{ce^{k \mu} + e^{-k \mu} /c}+ \ldots$$ as the leading term in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have not previously seen the saddle point method; it is said to be applied to complex integrals on the complex plane $I(z) = \int_C f(z)e^{\lambda g(z)} \, dz$, where $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$. I have also found cases where people estimate $I(N) = \int_a^b f(x)e^{N g(x)} \, dx$, where $N$ is large. So why can we use this approximation here? Another question is what do you mean exactly by $\langle y \rangle$?

Comment: I have also now checked whether numerically for some arbitrary $\mu$, $\sigma$, $k$, and $c$ this approximation holds and it doesn't for different sets of parameters (e.g. $\mu=1$, $\sigma=3$, $k=2$, and $c=7$). So what are the conditions to use this approximation?

Comment: @Lidiia 1. Taking the ratio of the next-to-leading term and the leading term, a decent  approximation can be expected if $f^{\prime \prime}(\mu)\sigma^2/(2 f(\mu)) <\!< 1$. In the case of your function, this condition becomes $(k \sigma)^2(\tanh^2( k \mu+ \ln c)-1/2) <\!< 1$ being clearly *not* fulfilled for your parameter choice. 2. $\lambda \to \infty$ corresponds to $\sigma \to 0$ for the Gauss pdf. Qualitatively, a good result of the saddle point method can be expected, if the function $f(x)$ does not vary "too much" in the interval $[\mu-\sigma,\mu+ \sigma]$.

Comment: @Lidiia ctd: 3. $\langle f(x) \rangle$ is the expectation value of the function $f(x)$ in the Gauss distribution.